# Why isn't my .exe file building for no reason?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 since a long time. I was modifying somethings about adding a new project into it. I didnt feel it was working so I deleted those files and tried to build it again. **BUT ITS NOT WORKING!**

I don't know what changed but now no .exe file is working in Debug mode. **I'm so scared** since I've spent a considerable amount of time on the project and I have to turn in the code by the weekend. All my cpp files are still here but suddenly I can't run the code??
 :((

[image: error screenshot]

[image: project properties]

CLEAN OUTPUT

```
1>------ Skipped Clean: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>------ Clean started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Clean started: Project: Neuro-Endo-Trainer-Activity-Tracker, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Clean started: Project: app, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>------ Clean started: Project: libopentld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>------ Clean started: Project: cvblobs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>------ Clean started: Project: config++, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>------ Clean started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Clean: 7 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

BUILD OUTPUT

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/3rdparty/cvblobs/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/3rdparty/libconfig/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/libopentld/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/app/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Build started: Project: config++, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: cvblobs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: libopentld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/src/3rdparty/libconfig/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/3rdparty/libconfig/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
3>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/src/3rdparty/cvblobs/CMakeLists.txt
3>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/3rdparty/cvblobs/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
4>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/src/libopentld/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/libopentld/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  grammar.c
3>  blob.cpp
4>  ImAcq.cpp
2>  libconfig.c
2>  scanctx.c
2>  scanner.c
2>  strbuf.c
2>  Generating Code...
3>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\cvblobs\blob.cpp(586): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
3>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\cvblobs\blob.cpp(587): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
3>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\cvblobs\blob.cpp(592): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
3>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\cvblobs\blob.cpp(603): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
3>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\cvblobs\blob.cpp(624): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
2>  libconfigcpp.cc
3>  BlobContour.cpp
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(201): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(216): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(217): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(218): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(219): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(220): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(221): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(222): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(223): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(224): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(225): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(226): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(228): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(231): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(232): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(233): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(234): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(235): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(236): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(237): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(238): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(241): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(244): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(248): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(298): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(301): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(305): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(308): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(312): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(314): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(326): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(327): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(382): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
2>c:\users\akhil\desktop\endoscopy\endo-trainer-activity-tracker-scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(385): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)

5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(218): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(219): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(220): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(221): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(222): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(223): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(224): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(225): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(226): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(228): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(231): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(232): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(233): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(234): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(235): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(236): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(237): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(238): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(241): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(244): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(248): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(298): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(301): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(305): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(308): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(312): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(314): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(326): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(327): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(382): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(385): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(386): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(389): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(390): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(393): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\src\3rdparty\libconfig\libconfig.h++(396): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
5>  pegBox.cpp
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(47): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(55): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(87): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(117): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(157): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(169): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(172): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(180): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(187): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(191): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\pegBox.cpp(200): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
5>  RingBox.cpp
5>..\..\..\src\app\RingBox.cpp(33): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\RingBox.cpp(66): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\RingBox.cpp(86): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>  Scorer.cpp
5>  Settings.cpp
5>..\..\..\src\app\Settings.cpp(67): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'
5>  Trajectory.cpp
5>c:\users\akhil\desktop\opencvnew\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\logger.h(66): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
5>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(205): note: see declaration of 'fopen'
5>  util.cpp
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(36): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(50): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(75): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(81): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(91): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(102): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(115): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(125): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>..\..\..\src\app\util.cpp(135): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
5>  Generating Code...
5>Scorer.obj : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
5>  app.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Akhil\Desktop\endoscopy\Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer\build\lib\Debug\app.lib
6>------ Build started: Project: Neuro-Endo-Trainer-Activity-Tracker, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
6>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/src/app/CMakeLists.txt
6>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/app/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
7>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/CMakeLists.txt
7>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
8>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 7 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild?

Comment: *"for no reason"* I bet there's a reason.

Comment: Yeah I have done clean and rebuild still doesnt work :(

Comment: I recommend performing a clean build and then inspecting the full build output from the output tab. If nothing jumps out at you, paste the build output into the question. We can't do much with images, unfortunately, and all they do for you is chum for downvotes. Provide plain text where possible.

Comment: I know there must be some reason, just that I can't see it right now :(

Comment: Wait, why don't you just compare it to the previous version you checked into your source control system.  Or pull that version and start over?

Comment: "_I have done clean and rebuild still doesnt work_" - So it compiles ok? - but you can''t run the program?

Comment: 1) "Why isn't my .exe file building for no reason?" But the error that you show states "Unable to start program".. So can't you build it, or run it? 2) "_I'm so scared since I've spent a considerable amount of time on the project and I have to turn in the code by the weekend._" This is why you don't leave your work until the last week.

Comment: Go look manually at the output directory and see if there is an executable there. Try running it manually. The debugger's Command property might just not be looking for the right file.

Comment: If the build completes successfully and generates an executable, make sure that whatever you are using for antivirus doesn't delete the file shortly after.

Comment: There is no executable generated in my output directory, I've checked manually too

Comment: My antivirus isn't disturbing I'm sure since 20-30 minutes before everything was fine

Comment: There is no source control system actually. It's my own solo project which I forgot to store backup of :(

Comment: Go to Build -> Configuration Manager. Your executable doesn't seem to be part of the current configuration. Make sure Build is checked for the configuration you are using. Edit : Nevermind, looks like it is. But better check this anyway.

Comment: Build is checked for all configurations except INSTALL. It was never set for INSTALL even while it was working fine...

Comment: `6>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/endoscopy/Endo-trainer-Activity-Tracker-Scorer/build/src/app/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.` is suspicious. Maybe that file is not cleaned correctly. Delete manually and try again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Actually when I output whole build the total length is 81k characters which is way over the limit of 30k, so I removed some warnings which would come while it was working fine too.

Comment: What files did you actually delete? Also keep in mind that the source should still be there so a) you can still turn it in, and b) create a new solution from the source files if you need to--even if you have to copy and paste the source files.

Comment: `app.vcxproj -> C:\...\app.lib`.  A library??  Project > Properties > General, "Configuration type" setting.

Comment: I suggest you could try :1,Delete output directory (specified by CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX).2,Delete cmake cache file (CMakeCache.txt) 3,Re-configure & re-generate project